# including ITK to existing project

Tags: c++, dll, itk

I am trying to include ITK filters to my dynamic library using VS2015, to be run on external software. I am including the headers and libs folders correctly and linking the following libs specifically: 
ITKCommon-5.0.lib
itkv3p_netlib-5.0.lib
itkvnl-5.0.lib
itkvnl_algo-5.0.lib

It compiles correctly put when I start my external application, it says the .dll cannot be found. I traced the problem to a single line here:

```
#include <itkImage.h>
#include "itkImportImageFilter.h"

typedef itk::Image< float, 2 > ItkImage2;

ItkImage2::Pointer output;

typedef itk::ImportImageFilter<float, 2>  ImportFilterType;

ImportFilterType::Pointer importFilter = ImportFilterType::New();  <-- HERE it faills
```

Is this a smartpointer problem? i get no linking errors.
Using Cmake with CmakeList.txt creates a world of other problems and seems not feasible...

thx!

Comment: If the third party libraries are `dynamic` then you'll need to ensure that their associated `dll`'s are in your target output directory (where the `executable` for your application resides). Place the `dll`'s beside your `exe`.

Comment: In your installer you create to install your application bundle the required third party .dlls. have your installer install them in the same folder as your executable.